# Why cant I sculpt over my model?

Tags: sculpting

I wanted to create a simple dragon/snake thing which I managed to do, but now when I try to sculpt (to add the eyes and some texture and manual smoothing to make it less boxy), my computer lags and doesn't seem to want to let me. I have a powerful computer so its not hardware. Plus [the file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yaY8ydDqS3W_NV407RUyBEBlwlAJIvD) is less than 1mb. Can someone please have a peak and let me know what I've done wrong and how I can fix this without redoing? Im new to blender.
N

Answer (score 1):

It possibly could be that you have not applied the transform. Try using space to search and looking for 'Apply object transform' and 'Apply visual transform'.

It will also help to have dyntopo checked if you do not have it on already.

Comment: or have a multiresolution modifer, some people (including me) prefer it to dynamic topology. :)

Comment: It turns out I had to apply the subdivision modifier before entering into sculpt mode.